# retrieving two consecutive records from sqlite by passing two values in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I am trying to fetch two consecutive records by passing two values,one value for first record and another value for second record.

My table name is Extractor, which contains three columns 1)wordText 2)wordID 3)rowID(primary key)

**Questions:**

1)can we write single query to get two consecutive rows by passing parameters?
2)If above query is possible how we can able to achieve this?

**My approach:** so far I tried with below query

SELECT * FROM Extractor where wordText LIKE "firstWord"

after fetching all the records using above query  I am again querying for other record, I know this sequential approach is not good one for  fetching few record from 10000 rows.

Comment: is "firstWord" the exact value or the part of the value?

Comment: Thanks for reply.First word is exact only.

Comment: You mean there are many rows(more than two) that have wordText=firstWord but you just want to get two any rows having that word?

Comment: yes Neo, your correct. But i want the records which are having wordText=firtWord and the next record of wordText should be equal to my secondWord .

Comment: How have u executed the statement? have u used this sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW inside while loop?

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries dont concern themselves with retrieving consecutive records. They concern themselves with retrieving records based on criteria into discrete results.

If you want a row and the next consecutive row, you could assign synthetic keys to each row and query for the first ID and then request the next ID.

Also the storage order of rows in an RDMS is not necessarily sorted or guaranteed to remain constant over time.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable words.I am not much into sqlite query can you please provide me some more info.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * FROM Extractor WHERE wordText IN ('firstWord', 'secondWord')
```